# Click event after append Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append, jquery-click-event

I'm playing around with some Jquery, json and Ajax.

If the fa-plus got clicked it needs to disappear and fa-mines needs to show.
the problem is it doesn't do anything. not even the console.log('clicked')

I've got document ready and: `$(document).on('click', '.open', function() {}`

I'm lost here.. hope you guys can help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Cocktail.getAll().done(function(data){
        var list = $('.list-group');

        for (var i = 0; i < data.cocktails.length; i++) {
            list.append('<li class="list-group-item"><h3>' + data.cocktails[i].name + '</h3><i class="fa fa-plus"><i class="fa fa-minus hide"></i>');
        }

    }).fail(function(data){
        console.warn('fetching failed');
        console.warn(data);
    }).always(function(){
        console.log('this is what I always do');
    });


    var open = $('.fa-plus');
    var close = $('.fa-minus');

    $(document).on('click', '.open', function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('hide');
        close.removeClass('hide');

    });
});
```

Comment: And do you have any elements with the `.open` class?

Comment: show relevant html code

Comment: Ahh damn, you're right @adeneo changed '.open' to open. now the console log works but the hide doesn't

Comment: can u show what error u r getting on console?

Comment: @amitguptageek Console isn't giving me anything except the console logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of maintaining two elements, just update the class on a single element.  then you don't need to show / hide.

```
$(document).on('click', '.fa', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
});
```

Comment: You're right on this. If you use this you can remove the <i class="fa fa-minus hide"></i> part.